# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of post object in React Component

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a mini React app and have run into a problem. To give you some background, I am using `jsonplaceholder.typicode/com/posts`  to fetch some posts and display them on the home page.

When I click on an individual post, the idea is that it should take me to a different page and display the title & body of the clicked post. I am able to fetch the respective single post (postFound) from the posts array when I click on a post. By the way, I am using Context API for state management. And console.log(postFound) returns the post object which has title and body properties.

But when I am trying to access the title property of the postFound object inside my JSX, it is throwing an error: `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined in React"`. Where is the problem?

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { postsContext } from "../../Context";

const SinglePostPage = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const postIdNum = parseInt(id);
  const { posts } = useContext(postsContext);

  const postFound = posts.find((post) => post.id === postIdNum);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{postFound.title}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SinglePostPage;
```

Comment: The error happens before it finds a post, you should check if there is a post. `{postFound && <div><h1>{postFound.title}</h1></div>`

Comment: Array.prototype.find returns undefined if no item found. In this case, you catch the error.

Comment: @merko Thanks. Solved. http requests take time. So, I will have to render postFound conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Your postFound is undefined which means that your declaration is unsuccessful i.e there is not post with that ID. Instead you can have a check which tells the user that the post was not found and renders a message.

```
const postFound = posts.find((post) => post.id === postIdNum);
      if (!postFound return <h1>Post not found <h1/>
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{postFound.title}</h1>
        </div>
      );
```

Comment: But when I console.log(postFound), I get the post object with title and body properties. This means postFound exists. Its only when try to access the title or body property, I get the error.

Comment: Can you add the posts array and the content in the postFound to your question?

Comment: What was the issue? Just curious

Comment: @MB59, I don't know the issue. But when I conditionally rendered postFound object, it worked fine. Like so: let postFoundRendered; if(postFound) {postFoundRendered = postFound} and then inside JSX, <h1>{postFoundrendered.title}</h1>